# Binding a list to a Gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm struggling to get my head around this, i have a list collection with the following that i'm trying to bind to a GridView;

```
  public class GetMenu
    {
        public string titleName { get; set; }
        public string imagePath { get; set; }
    }

    List<GetMenu> Menu = new List<GetMenu>()
    {
        new GetMenu(){titleName = "one", imagePath = "image.jpg"},
        new GetMenu(){titleName = "one", imagePath = "image.jpg"}    
    };
```

My XAML code looks like;

```
  <GridView x:Name="MenuViewGrid" TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="116,136,116,46" Margin="0,0,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        SelectionMode="None" IsSwipeEnabled="false" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="275" Height="425" >
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=imagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=titleName}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="25"  Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

In my head i thought i'd be able to do a simple;

```
MenuViewGrid.ItemsSource = GetMenu;
```

But when doing the above i get an error message saying it's a type but i'm trying to use it as a variable. I can't understand this as i've used the code on Windows Phone before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `GetMenu` by `Menu` (`GetMenu` is your class, `Menu` is your list):

```
MenuViewGrid.ItemsSource = Menu;
```

Comment: agh, i've been staring at this code for the last two hours and it was something as simple as that. I really need to learn to have a break when stuck on things.